Headset bearing/seal order for Bianchi Specialissima
I'm assembling a Bianchi Specialissima Comp (2024), and am struggling to figure out the order of these two components:

bottom headset bearing
bottom headset seal (I think it's a seal, it's rubbery)

Attached photos of the two - does the seal go on top (it seems to fit better that way) or on the bottom of the bearing (that would make more sense to me for preventing dirt getting in)?
Advice would be appreciated (maybe I have the orientation wrong too?)
I wasn't able to find a manual that addressed the headset (or even listed the model they use).
The two pieces:

Option 1:

Option 2:


This is not a seal, but a crown race and is supposed to be pressed onto the fork crown below bottom bearing as shown in your last picture.
If you look at the bottom bearing closer you will see that its inner surface is chamfered at an angle where its supposed to interface with the crown race. The angle of the crown race cone will match the angle of the bearing.
Since this is not a split race you will have to take extra care to make sure it is fully pressed onto the fork crown. It is an interference fit and if not seated fully your headset will develop play when riding.

Found a Bianchi document that has a headset that looks similar to yours.
Here's the diagram

Here's the document
The "lower cone" goes on the bottom.
